# Recusive ML function of exponential with three variable helper function

Tags: recursion, sml, exponential, ml

I need help figuring out what I need to do for the helper function recursively, I am kinda lost of in what I need to do for the helper function.

Here is the question and the example input.
[image: The example input and output]

Here is the example of what the helper function does

[image: The helper function example]

This is what I have written so far
[image: My attempt]

Comment: The helper function should call itself, not the function it's "helping".  (And please don't post pictures of code, post the code.)

Comment: Please post text _as_ text where possible. (as opposed to an image of text)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need to change the notation slightly to find the solution.

Instead of a*b<sup>n</sup>, write `exp3(a, b, n)`.

Then the example says,

```
  exp(3,4)
= exp3(1, 3, 4)
= exp3(1*3, 3, 4-1)
= exp3(3*3, 3, 3-1)
= exp3(3*9, 3, 2-1)
= exp3(3*27, 3, 1-1)
= 81
```

And you have actually been given the solution – the text literally says "Lemma 4.15 provides a base case, Lemma 4.16 a recursive case".

Lemma 4.15:

```
exp3(a, b, 0) = a
```

Lemma 4.16:

```
exp3(a, b, n) = exp3(a * b, b, n - 1)
```

And the function that needs help should only have one case; the first "step" shown in the example:

```
fun exp(a, b) = exp3(1, a, b)
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and the advice.

Comment: Do you understand that it's not just "clarification" and "advice", but a solution? You just need to put the pieces together.